# Converting existing (visual designer) build to yaml based build

Tags: azure-devops

Does anyone know if it is possible to replace the existing build definition for a repository that was created via the visual designer with a yaml based build definition?

Going via `Pipelines > Builds > New` I can add a new definition, create a yaml and commit to the repo. However, this is a new build with a new pipeline ID. We have over 1.5 years of build history with linked work items on some repos, which we query via REST APIs as part of other processes. If I delete the old definition after creating the new yaml definition that history disappears with it (specifically the connection with work items). The leaves me really only with the option to keep the old definitions (I could put them in an archive folder).

Ideally, I would like to simply replace the build definition on a given repo, with given pipeline ID, with the yaml file in the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, this is not possible, you cannot edit existing build to become a yaml build, unfortunately.